# Extract string of numbers from variable with Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with a variable with strings of text like this:

```
row  path
1    /998777/kkjs/lksjaflkjsdf/sdfñklñ{sdf
2   /ñljasdfkgbsdf/5854654/lsjflkjsdf/asdfasdfsdf
3    /11544/sdfsdf/asdfsdfasdfdsf/sssfdsfdsdf
```

How can I query this table to extract the numbers for the variable so I get a new variable with:

```
row  path2
1    998777
2    5854654
3    11544
```

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '/998777/kkjs/lksjaflkjsdf/sdfñklñ{sdf' path UNION ALL
  SELECT '/ñljasdfkgbsdf/5854654/lsjflkjsdf/asdfasdfsdf' UNION ALL
  SELECT '/11544/sdfsdf/asdfsdfasdfdsf/sssfdsfdsdf' 
)
SELECT path, REGEXP_EXTRACT(path, r'/(\d+)/') path2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row path                                            path2    
1   /998777/kkjs/lksjaflkjsdf/sdfñklñ{sdf           998777   
2   /ñljasdfkgbsdf/5854654/lsjflkjsdf/asdfasdfsdf   5854654  
3   /11544/sdfsdf/asdfsdfasdfdsf/sssfdsfdsdf        11544
```

Comment: Edited the question as I only want to retain full set of numbers among // al the rest should be excluded

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(str, '[^0-9]', '')
```

Comment: This keeps all numbers however there are numbers among the rest of the string such as:
/998777/kkjs/lksjaflkjsdf/sdfñklñ9ddsdf/99h/

so this includes 99 as well which is not the expected behaviour

Comment: @EGM8686 . . . There are none in your sample strings and it is not clear if you want to keep all digits or just specific digits.  If specific digits, you should be clear on what the rules are.